# Flask project works on local machine but returns 500 error on remote server

Tags: flask, mod-wsgi, wtforms

I am new in the coding arena.  I used the instructions at the following link to build my web app and it is working on my local machine with no problem.

https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-deploy-a-flask-application-on-an-ubuntu-vps

Once I deployed it to my remote server, I received a 500 error.  The error log shows:

```
[Tue Oct 09 02:42:27.517360 2018] [wsgi:error] [pid 6257:tid 140375628965632] [client 99.111.155.184:22844] mod_wsgi (pid=6257): Target WSGI script '/var/www/PersonalApp/personalapp.wsgi' cannot be loaded as Python module.
[Tue Oct 09 02:42:27.517374 2018] [wsgi:error] [pid 6257:tid 140375628965632] [client 99.111.155.184:22844] mod_wsgi (pid=6257): Exception occurred processing WSGI script '/var/www/PersonalApp/personalapp.wsgi'.
[Tue Oct 09 02:42:27.517397 2018] [wsgi:error] [pid 6257:tid 140375628965632] [client 99.111.155.184:22844] Traceback (most recent call last):
[Tue Oct 09 02:42:27.517423 2018] [wsgi:error] [pid 6257:tid 140375628965632] [client 99.111.155.184:22844]   File "/var/www/PersonalApp/personalapp.wsgi", line 8, in <module>
[Tue Oct 09 02:42:27.517460 2018] [wsgi:error] [pid 6257:tid 140375628965632] [client 99.111.155.184:22844]     from PersonalApp import app
[Tue Oct 09 02:42:27.517469 2018] [wsgi:error] [pid 6257:tid 140375628965632] [client 99.111.155.184:22844]   File "/var/www/PersonalApp/PersonalApp/__init__.py", line 6, in <module>
[Tue Oct 09 02:42:27.517482 2018] [wsgi:error] [pid 6257:tid 140375628965632] [client 99.111.155.184:22844]     from wtforms import Form, StringField, PasswordField, TextAreaField, validators
[Tue Oct 09 02:42:27.517518 2018] [wsgi:error] [pid 6257:tid 140375628965632] [client 99.111.155.184:22844] ImportError: No module named wtforms
```

**Project Struture:**

```
|--------PersonalApp
|----------------PersonalApp
|-----------------------static
|-----------------------templates
|-----------------------venv
|-----------------------__init__.py
|----------------personalapp.wsgi
```

**personalapp.wsgi**

```
#! /usr/bin/python

import sys
import logging
logging.basicConfig(stream=sys.stderr)
sys.path.insert(0,"/var/www/PersonalApp/")

from PersonalApp import app as application
```

**__init__.py (partial code)**

```
from datetime import datetime
from sqlalchemy.sql.functions import now
from flask import Flask, render_template, flash, redirect, url_for, request
from flask_sqlalchemy.model import Model
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
from wtforms import Form, StringField, TextAreaField, validators


app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['SECRET_KEY'] = 'secret_key'


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(host='0.0.0.0', port=5000)
```

**The following are the same on both local and remote:**

```
Server version: Apache/2.4.18 (Ubuntu)
Python 2.7.12

server
Package          Version
---------------- -------
Click            7.0
Flask            1.0.2
Flask-SQLAlchemy 2.3.2
Flask-WTF        0.14.2
itsdangerous     0.24
Jinja2           2.10
MarkupSafe       1.0
pip              18.1
psycopg2         2.7.5
setuptools       40.4.3
SQLAlchemy       1.2.12
Werkzeug         0.14.1
wheel            0.32.1
WTForms          2.2.1

VERSION="16.04.5 LTS (Xenial Xerus)"
```

**The only difference between the 2 are:**

***server***

```
Ubuntu 16.04.5 LTS (GNU/Linux 4.4.0-1069-aws x86_64)
```

***local machine***

```
Linux Lite 3.8 (GNU/Linux 4.4.0-138-generic i686)Linux Lite 3.8 (GNU/Linux 4.4.0-138-generic i686)
```

I am not sure what I am missing since it is working on my local machine.  Any guidance would be greatly appreciated.  Thank you in advance!

Comment: are you sure that when you list your python packages that you have your virtual environment active (that WTForms is actually installed in the virtual environment) and that when you run your app its in the activated virtual environment?

Comment: Thank you for your reply.  I typed source venv/bin/activate and the (venv) is at the head of my prompt.  I type pip list and the list I provided is what is returned.

Answer (score 1):

I'd recommend to add a `import sys, os; print(sys.version); print(sys.executable);` as a first line in your `init.py` to check which python interpreter your mod_wsgi uses. If it differs, then you should install packages for mod_wsgi's python interpreter or specify path to your desired interpreter with all packages already installed (not sure that it's possible in DO).

Comment: Thank you for your input.  I added the lines to the __init__.py file per your recommendation.  The following is the output:

2.7.12 (default, Dec  4 2017, 14:50:18)
[GCC 5.4.0 20160609]
/usr/bin/python

Comment: Then check if required packages are installed for that particular interpreter with `/usr/bin/python -m pip list`.

Comment: all of the required pkgs appear in the result of that command:

certifi (2018.8.24)
chardet (3.0.4)
Click (7.0)
Flask (1.0.2)
Flask-HTTPAuth (3.2.4)
Flask-SQLAlchemy (2.3.2)
Flask-WTF (0.14.2)
httplib2 (0.11.3)
idna (2.7)
itsdangerous (0.24)
Jinja2 (2.10)
MarkupSafe (1.0)
oauth2client (4.1.3)
pip (8.1.1)
psycopg2 (2.6.1)
psycopg2-binary (2.7.5)
pyasn1 (0.4.4)
pyasn1-modules (0.2.2)
requests (2.19.1)
rsa (3.4.2)
setuptools (20.7.0)
six (1.11.0)
SQLAlchemy (1.2.12)
urllib3 (1.23)
virtualenv (16.0.0)
Werkzeug (0.14.1)
wheel (0.29.0)
WTForms (2.2.1)

Comment: I just install VirtualBox and Vagrant on a Windows 10 machine I have at home (configured with Ubuntu as well).  I used scp to copy the project folder from my local server to the Windows pc (like I did to the remote server).  I ran the program and it works with no issues.  Maybe I should rm the dir from the remote server and try again.

Answer (score 0):

I updated my project structure and now it is working on the remote.  I did NOT change the original structure on the local machine, which still works.  Interesting.  Maybe I overlooked some small detail.  Thank you again for attempting to help me resolve my issue.

```
   yourapp/
    config.py
    __init__.py
    views.py
    models.py
    forms.py
    static/
```

Comment: If you really want to accept the answer of your own, you’d better double check and dig deeper on that issue to specify that “small detail”. Since it would be a mislead for others if that is not the reason causing the issue.

Comment: @Light.G Thank you.  You are correct in that I did not get a solution to my issue.  The code was exactly the same on the 2 local machines machines as the remote; however, the remote was the only one not working (returning errors).  I am new to coding, so I was only going by the log file (sudo nano /var/log/apache2/error.log’).  I did not see the need to compare files since they were identical, the pip lists were the same, etc.  I will remove the check...maybe someone else can offer a suggestion on what else I could investigate.